# Crave for? Can you crave for a college?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Can you crave for a college? Or any other object like a book or a movie? I am using the word crave to show the strong need for a college. Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It's not exactly idiomatic but sure, why not?  Probably healthier than craving for some other things! :-)

Comment: Generally in English one craves something, rather than craving _for_ it. If you want to use _for_, you can use a nominalization: _I have a craving for chocolate_. _To have a craving_ means to crave permanently, just like _to have an infirmity_ means to be sick permanently.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I've never heard that to have a craving is permanent, like an infirmity.  If you satisfy the craving, it goes away...although maybe just temporarily! :-)

Comment: It at least goes on for a while, though perhaps not to the end of life. The point is that the construction with _have_ lengthens the scope of the emotion. There's a similar ambiguity in expressing any emotion -- is it temporary or will it last? Hard to tell, especially for other people.

Comment: Grammatically, it works. However, most of us are likely to express cravings for elemental needs like food, water or air. One could express a craving for a new car, for instance, but this would sound practically metaphorical.

Comment: To have a craving for is to desire to indulge (eg a curry; chocolate) or perhaps to possess. How does this work with a college?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "**I craved for France**, and with twenty pounds in my pocket I went to Paris, got an office boy's job in a photographic firm and then became a traveler in the glue and shellac trade." From [_Introduction to At Home and Abroad_](https://www.google.com/books/edition/At_Home_and_Abroad/9QLuHOvYbMQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I+craved+for%22&pg=PT3&printsec=frontcover) by [V. S. Pritchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V._S._Pritchett)

Comment: @Eddie Kal A transferred usage; 'I craved for France' = 'I longed to imbibe the atmosphere, visit the fleshpots ... of Paris etc. Transferred usages are usually not fully interchangeable.' Certainly 'I craved a college' is so unnatural-sounding as to warrant a downmark in an A-level essay. 'I craved [for] the college life Jill had enthused about so wildly' works.

Answer (score 2):

Saying "I crave for this movie" is not correct and would not be used by native modern English speakers. This is because the verb "crave" takes a direct object, not a prepositional phrase.

It's confusing because you *can* say "I have a craving for this movie". But in that case, "craving" is a noun and so it does not take a direct object, and a preposition is necessary.

Bad English:

- I crave for college
- I am craving for college

Good English:

- I crave college (or I crave seeing my favorite movie)
- I am craving college (or I am craving seeing my favorite movie)
- I have a craving for college (or I have a craving for seeing my favorite movie).
- *[formal/out of date]* I long for college (or I long to see my favorite movie).

Comment: While I agree "crave for something" is bad English and sounds completely non-idiomatic to me, it is indeed used by some native speakers. "**I craved for France**, and with twenty pounds in my pocket I went to Paris, got an office boy's job in a photographic firm and then became a traveler in the glue and shellac trade." From the introduction to _At Home and Abroad_ by [V. S. Pritchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V._S._Pritchett)